# Updating a badge when a new item is added to a list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, ajax

Hello I am trying to update a badge every time a new item is added to the list. I am making an Ajax call to the list and created a function with a counter; I also created a function with a setInterval calling the counter function.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var badgeContainer = document.getElementById('services');
    //Create counter
    var counter = document.createElement('div');
    counter.setAttribute('id', 'counter');
    counter.classList.add('counter');
    var counterText = document.createElement('p');
    counterText.setAttribute('id', 'counterText');


     $.ajax({
        url: "http://bcnet/Sandbox/juandev/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Qlinks')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var items = data.d.results;
        //console.log(items);


        if (items.length > 0 ) {

        badgeContainer.appendChild(counter);
        counter.appendChild(counterText);

var count = ' ';

        function changeCounter() {
            count++;
            var newCounterText = count;
            counterText.innerHTML = newCounterText;


        }//end changeCounter function   

        changeCounter();

        function newUpdate() {
        update = setInterval(changeCounter, 2000);

    }//endf newUpdate function

    newUpdate();

    }//en if statement

                },
             error: function(data) {
             alert("Error: " + data);
        }
    }); //End Service Icons  //End Service Icons

 }); //End ready function  

 /*setInterval(function() {
  //your jQuery ajax code
}, 1000 * 60 * X); // where X is your every X minutes*/

/*function send(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "test.php",
        success:function(data)
        {
            //console.log the response
            console.log(data);
            //Send another request in 10 seconds.
            setTimeout(function(){
                send();
            }, 10000);
        }
    });
}
//Call our function
send();*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of nested functions that might not be optimized. As you are already using jquery I think you could use something like this for your script editor:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../SiteAssets/js/test01.js"></script> 
<div id="itemCounter"></div>
```

And this for the linked test01.js file (makes it easier to edit):

```
function RefreshCounter() {
$.ajax({
    url: "../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test01')/items",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var items = data.d.results;
        //console.log(items);

        if (items.length > 0 ) {
            $('#itemCounter').html('\
                <div id="counter">\
                    <p id="counterText">' + items.length + '</p>\
                </div>\
            ');
        }
    }
});    
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(RefreshCounter, 2000);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @SteveT. I was working on a different script so it compares the current date vs the created date of the item. if there is a new item it will create a badge with the number of new items created.

Comment: So this would probably be a new question. Is this one answered?

Comment: this is one is new and has not been answered